# iOS - Chromecast integration with MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to provide lock screen controls

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, google-cast, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I'm developing an iOS Obj-C app that uses the GoogleCast Framework.

I am trying to get the lock screen controls working via `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`

I have added the correct permissions to my app to support backgrounding.

I am initialising the cast device like so:

`self.chromeCastDeviceManager = [[GCKDeviceManager alloc] initWithDevice:self.selectedChromeCastDevice clientPackageName:[info objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"] ignoreAppStateNotifications:YES];`

When I launch the media on the receiver, I try to init the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` when I get a successful playback response.

```
NSInteger result = [_castControlChannel play]; 

if (!result) {
    //launch has worked
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

     Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

     if (playingInfoCenter) {

         NSDictionary *songInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Test artist", MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                                   @"Test title", MPMediaItemPropertyTitle,
                                   @"Test Album", MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle,
                                   nil];
         [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
     }
}
```

I'm starting to believe that `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` only provides controls for media sessions when they're loaded in via `AVKit/ AVFoundation`? Am I correct in saying this?

If that is true, I could probably create an `AVKit/ AVFoundation` a NSInteger long with the `play method` on the Chromecast. Then force the AVPlayer to be hidden and silent. I can then catch the media controls and redirect to the Chromecast?

I assume the Youtube app on iOS does it this way? Both Netflix and Spotify both don't support the lockscreen controls when casting to a chromecast.

Comment: Spotify has this feature also, I am itching to find whats the trick to it, are there any new developments on the matter?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a solution to present the player controls in the lock screen. I am using some hacks to work, like method_exchangeImplementations and a mute sound to play and mock the player.

I have also replied in this post [Does google chromecast iOS SDK support lock screen controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824683/does-google-chromecast-ios-sdk-support-lock-screen-controls)

So far it works ok, but probably still needs improvement.

Take a look at https://github.com/peantunes/google-cast-ios-lock-screen